# Why am I getting segmentation error when the input is a matrix of order>2?

Tags: c, arrays

The question is to find the determinant of a NXN matrix in C language. I wrote the following code. I am getting the output for a n=2 matrix. But for n>2, the program is saying 'segmentation fault (core dumped)'. Please help me with it. I have tried writing the code as correct as possible. Any highlighting of mistakes in the syntax would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance. (I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Terminal.)

```
Input - 2 (Order of Matrix)
        1 (Enter the Elements)
        2
        3
        4
Output -1 2 (Entered Matrix)
        3 4  
       -2 (Value of Determinant)
Input - 3 (Order of Matrix)
        1 (Enter the Elements)
        2
        3
        4
        5
        6 
        7
        8
        9
Output -1 2 3 (Entered Matrix)
        4 5 6
        7 8 9 
        Segementation Fault(Core Dumped)
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
int determinent(int n,int p[n][n]);
int main()
{
int n,i,j;
printf("Enter the order of the matrix:\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
int a[n][n];
printf("Enter the elements of the NXN matrix.\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    }
}
printf("The entered matrix is:\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");
printf("The determinent of the matrix is %d\n",determinent(n,a));
return 0;
}

int determinent(int n,int p[n][n])
{
int det,k,m,s=1,i,j,l=0;
if(n==2)
{
    det = p[0][0]*p[1][1] - p[0][1]*p[1][0];
}
else
{
    for(k=0;k<n;k++,s=-s,l++)
    {
        if(l==0)
        {
            det = 0;
        }

        int b[n-1][n-1];
        m = (p[0][k])*(s);
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n-1;j++)
            {
                if(k==0)
                {
                    b[i][j] = p[i+1][j+1];
                }
                else
                {
                    int c;
                    for(c=0;c<k;c++)
                    {   
                        b[i][j] = p[i+1][j+1];
                    }
                    for(c=k+1;c<n;c++)
                    {
                        b[i][j] = p[i+1][c]; 
                    }    
                }
            }
        }
    n = n-1;    
    det = det + m*determinent(n,b);
    }
    }
    return det;
}
```

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding: 1)  please indent the code consistently.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  2) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent).  4) variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  Single character names are meaningless.  5) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the posted output does not match what the posted code outputs.  This leads to confusion and will tend to get the question downvoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, you had infinite recursion leading to a stack overflow because you were passing the wrong value of `n` to the recursive call. Instead of `n--`, you should be passing `n-1`. Note that the value passed should not change in the `k`-loop, it should always be one less than the value passed in as a function argument.

Also mentioned in the comments, the upper bound for your `k` loop was off by one before your edit.

The remaining problem is how you fill the submatrix `b[n-1][n-1]`. What you are trying to achieve is to fill `b` with all the values of `p` except those in row `0` and those in column `k`. The loop over `c` is unnecessary, as is the special case for `k == 0`. The correct value to pick is `b[i][j] = p[i+1][(j < k) ? j : j+1]`. In other words, copy rows `1` to `n-1`. For each row, copy columns to the left of `k`, and after that add one to the column index to skip the `k`'th one.

Fixing these, the code produces the correct determinants for a few cases I tried.

Comment: That was a useful answer. I will try modifying the program. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. You got the solution. The problem was in the 'c' variable loop. I don't know, i will check it why it din't work, but yeah your method of writing b[ i ][ j ] worked like a charm. Again Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

- The 2 order matrix you make and get a determinant value, there logic
  is messing up , you are running into a infinite loop and finally you are trying to access a out of bound array value and core dump is occurring. I have attached the screen shot below for
  your reference.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAArY.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit